# How can I speed up an sql query that round trips between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, performance

These tables are not that big, but the time taken to process this query is long.

What can I do with the following queries to speed up the process taken to return results?

```
$msc=microtime(true);

$chat_alg = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT sid, COUNT(*) as frequency
    FROM plays
    WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY && sid != '' 
    GROUP BY sid
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row_chat_alg = mysqli_fetch_array($chat_alg)) {
    $chart_songs[] = $row_chat_alg['sid'];
}

$imploded_songs = implode($chart_songs, ',');

$projects = $dbh->query("
       SELECT * FROM music
       WHERE perms != 'c' && sid IN($imploded_songs) 
       ORDER BY FIELD(sid,$imploded_songs) 
       limit 50
");

$msc=microtime(true)-$msc;
echo ($msc*1000).' milliseconds';

...
Time taken: 9.5310001373291 milliseconds
```

This tables are growing, I'm worried that maintaining them will be a problem if this is already slow.

Comment: How about creating a function in mysql? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html, Example: http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/create-function-examples.html

Comment: @KeAn Ok, how will it speed up things? Please give an example.

Comment: Those queries shouldn't take much time. Are You using primary keys / foreign keys / indexes?

Comment: You can try changing the SQL Engine on your tables, if you use InnoDB and go to MyISAM the INSERT and SELECT transactions are faster. Read this StackOverFlow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678406/when-to-use-myisam-and-innodb

Comment: @Relm The database can process the information a lot faster than if you have to sidestep out into the php-interpreter and again insert a query.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I'm using a primary keys that are auto incremented on both tables. There's "sid" in table.music and "pid" in table.plays

Comment: @KeAn, I'm not inserting anything, I'm selecting, but going out and back inside process seems to make sense, how do you suppose I join the processes into one?

Comment: @Relm Sorry, bad choice of word, inserting. Meant to just do a query. It's been a while since I hacked mysql so it would take me to long to get up to speed but you should be able to put the first query result into a temporary table and then use that in the second query, all wrapped in a nice prepared statement or function.

Comment: @Relm But if the tables right now is not that big and you have a slow result, I agree with the others that perhaps you should look at something else first.

Comment: @Relm It's better to have one question only, in one site, not two. You can flag this question (for moderator attention) and explain what you want. If it is migrated to dba.se, the two questions can be merged.

Comment: @Pintouch what you wrote is an abomination, horrible and most of all - **completely not true**. On top of researching what InnoDB does and how it stacks up against MyISAM, I suggest that you consider removing your comment.

Comment: @N.B. I wrote that because 2 years ago I was working on a huge project that was requesting 10 000 points per chart. Without changing any request, I just change the SQL Engine of the related tables, and I had a gain of 10%. So I'm very interested to know your point of view about it?

Comment: @Pintouch - MyISAM is an old engine which worked great for the time when it was created. The largest difference between MyISAM and InnoDB is the fact that InnoDB is able to store working data set in RAM - that's the magic `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting. MySQL is being shipped with default values so it can work on really, really old and slow hardware. If not configured properly, it will yield abysmal performance. If tuned properly, it will yield incredible performance. InnoDB (tuned) outperforms MyISAM in every possible aspect. And yes, it even has that famed fulltext search supported.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks you for the clarification. I take note. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less like this...

```
SELECT m.*
     , COUNT(p.sid) frequency
  FROM music m
  JOIN plays p
    ON p.sid = m.sid
 WHERE p.time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
   AND p.sid != '' 
   AND m.perms != 'c' 
 GROUP 
    BY m.sid
 ORDER 
    BY frequency DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Ok i like the join, pretty, but seems to take longer than current one. Time taken: 30.5310001373291 milliseconds.

Comment: I'm surprised that my one query would take longer then your two queries, but really to help with issues of performance, we'd need to see the EXPLAIN for the above, as well as proper DDLs

Comment: Tried explaining, i get an undefined index.//$imploded_songs = implode($chart_songs, ',');
 $explain = mysqli_query($con ,"EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM music") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 $row_explain = mysqli_fetch_array($explain);
 echo $row_explain['title'];

Comment: What's the syntax for this?

Comment: Don't use PHP for the EXPLAIN! Just run it directly against the database in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query like this:

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM music
   INNER JOIN (SELECT sid, COUNT(*) as frequency
               FROM plays
               WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY && sid != '' 
               GROUP BY sid
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as innerresult ON music.sid = innerresult.sid
   WHERE perms != 'c' 
   ORDER BY music.sid 
   limit 50
```

Comment: MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner ON music.sid = inner.sid WHERE perms != 'c' ORDER BY music.sid '

Comment: Ok, which version are you using? Whats the full error message?

Comment: Version 5.4.3 There are two erros msgs.    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in C:\wamp\hazard\php\charts_feed.php on line 64

Comment: And the second one:  PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner ON music.sid = inner.sid WHERE perms != 'c' ORDER BY music.sid ' at line 7 in C:\wamp\hazard\php\charts_feed.php on line 64

Comment: `inner` is a reserved word.

Comment: DOH! Answer updated!

Comment: OK correct sql, but Time taken: 40.5310001373291 milliseconds more than the original.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete

```html
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
ORDER BY FIELD(sid,$imploded_songs)
```

Comment: The second query depends on this.